# Preg_match only working in order

Tags: php, mysql, get, preg-match, row

I am having problems with the following code. I am getting the users subjects using $_GET then sending it to the server to see if the row contains the subjects and if it does then it returns subject matches row for each row it matches. This currently works fine but if the user enters lets say "english,maths" and in the database it is listed as "maths, english" it will fail and will not echo that row although it is correct just in a different order. Is there anything I am doing wrong??

Thanks,

CurtisB

```
    $subjects = $_GET["subjects"];  
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC) and ($counter < $max)) 
    {
       if(preg_match('/'.$subjects.'/',$row['subjects'])){
       echo "subject matches row";         
        }
    }
```

UPDATE: Tried code below, which is echoing every row even if not the correct subject.

```
 function is_matched($subjectsFromUs, $subjectsFromDb){
        $subjectsFromUs = explode($subjectsFromUs, ',');
        $subjectsFromDb = explode($subjectsFromDb, ',');
        foreach($subjects as $s){
            if(!in_array($s, subjectsFromDb))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    } 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC) and ($counter < $max)) 
{
   if(is_matched($subjects,$row['subjects']) == true ){

echo "subjects matched";
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you shouldn't use regexp in such a case. You must just explode your $subjects parameter by ',' and traverse that array trough $row['subjects']:

```
  function is_matched($subjects, $subjectsFromDb){
        $subjects = explode(',', $subjects);
        $subjectsFromDb = explode(',', $subjectsFromDb);
        foreach($subjects as $s){
            if(!in_array($s, $subjectsFromDb))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I have tried this using the following code and I could not get it to work. It echoes now even when the row is not the correct subject. I will put the code above so you can see.

Comment: I have edited the code. Just forgot one $ and switch parameters in explode

Comment: after further investigation, this code is not exactly what I need because if in the mysql the row is "maths" and I enter in "maths,english" as a subject it will not return true only if I enter maths will it return true?

Comment: if you want to find rows that contains not all $subjects, but any of it, just change condition a little to that format
 function is_matched($subjects, $subjectsFromDb){
        $subjects = explode(',', $subjects);
        $subjectsFromDb = explode(',', $subjectsFromDb);
        foreach($subjects as $s){
            if(in_array($s, $subjectsFromDb))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }